# Electron IPC within Angular Controller

Tags: angularjs, ipc, electron

Just after a bit of advise please, is it possible to call ipc module from Angular Controller

```
 var ipc = require('ipc');
 ipc.send('asynchronous-message', 'ping');
```

I have tried with no success to send ipc message.

loaded from index.html creates BrowserWindow
main.js

```
ipc.on('asynchronous-message', function(event, arg) {
      console.log(arg);  // prints "ping"
      event.sender.send('asynchronous-reply', 'pong');
    });
```

Have read multiple articles on IPC, can not get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Developer error, I had the event listener within a function block so it was never getting called.

```
ipc.on('asynchronous-message', function(event, arg) {
      console.log(arg);  // prints "ping"
      event.sender.send('asynchronous-reply', 'pong');
    });
```

ipc works seamlessly from Angular

Comment: Can you send events and create event listeners inside a controller? In my case, the event listener never gets called with the response from main.

Comment: I found a solution! It was a scope issue that can be solved with $timeout: ipc.on('channel', function(event, data) {
$timeout(function () {
// assign the data in angular's scope here
}, 0);
});